# AF_XDP-Socket vs Linux Sockets: Why does my AF-XDP Socket lose packets whereas a generic linux socket doesn't?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, xdp-bpf

I am comparing AF-XDP sockets vs Linux Sockets in terms of how many packets they can process without packet-loss (packet-loss is defined as the RTP-sequence number of the current packet is not equal to the RTP-sequence number of the previous packet `+ 1`).

I noticed that my AF-XDP socket program (I can't determine if this problem is related to the kernel program or the user-space program) is losing around `~25` packets per second at around `390.000` packets per second whereas an equivalent program with generic linux sockets doesn't lose any packets.

I implemented a so-called `distributor`-program which loads the XDP-kernel program once, sets up a generic linux socket and adds `setsockopt(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP)` to this generic socket for every multicast-address I pass to the program via command line.
After this, the `distributor` loads the filedescriptor of a `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH` placed in the XDP-kernel program and inserts routes for the traffic in case a single AF-XDP socket needs to share its umem later on.

The XDP-kernel program then checks for each IPv4/UDP packet if there is an entry in that hash-map. This basically looks like this:

```
const struct pckt_idntfy_raw raw = {
    .src_ip = 0, /* not used at the moment */
    .dst_ip = iph->daddr,
    .dst_port = udh->dest,
    .pad = 0
};

const int *idx = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xdp_packet_mapping, &raw);

if(idx != NULL) {
    if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xsks_map, idx)) {
        bpf_printk("Found socket @ index: %d!\n", *idx);
        return bpf_redirect_map(&xsks_map, *idx, 0);
    } else {
        bpf_printk("Didn't find connected socket for index %d!\n", *idx);
    }
}
```

In case `idx` exists this means that there is a socket sitting behind that index in the `BPF_MAP_TYPE_XSKMAP`.

After doing all that the `distributor` spawns a new process via `fork()` passing all multicast-addresses (including destination port) which should be processed by that process (one process handles one RX-Queue). In case there are not enough RX-Queues, some processes may receive multiple multicast-addresses. This then means that they are going to use `SHARED UMEM`.

I basically oriented my AF-XDP user-space program on this example code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c

I am using the same `xsk_configure_umem`, `xsk_populate_fill_ring` and `xsk_configure_socket` functions.

Because I figured I don't need maximum latency for this application, I send the process to sleep for a specified time (around `1 - 2ms`) after which it loops through every AF-XDP socket (most of the time it is only one socket) and processes every received packet for that socket, verifying that no packets have been missed:

```
while(!global_exit) {
    nanosleep(&spec, &remaining);

    for(int i = 0; i < cfg.ip_addrs_len; i++) {
        struct xsk_socket_info *socket = xsk_sockets[i];
        if(atomic_exchange(&socket->stats_sync.lock, 1) == 0) {
            handle_receive_packets(socket);
            atomic_fetch_xor(&socket->stats_sync.lock, 1); /* release socket-lock */
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion there is nothing too fancy about this but somehow I lose `~25` packets at around `390.000` packets even though my UMEM is close to 1GB of RAM.

In comparison, my generic linux socket program looks like this (in short):

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);

/* setting some socket options */

struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = cfg->ip_addrs[0]->pckt.dst_port;
inet_aton(cfg->ip_addrs[0]->pckt.dst_ip, &sin.sin_addr);

if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on binding socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return - 1;
}

ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &intf);
```

The `distributor`-program creates a new process for every given multicast-ip in case generic linux sockets are used (because there are no sophisticated methods such as SHARED-UMEM in generic sockets I don't bother with multiple multicast-streams per process).
Later on I of course join the multicast membership:

```
struct ip_mreqn mreq;
memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(struct ip_mreqn));

const char *multicast_ip = cfg->ip_addrs[0]->pckt.dst_ip;

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, multicast_ip, &mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr)) {
    /* Local interface address */
    memcpy(&mreq.imr_address, &cfg->ifaddr, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    mreq.imr_ifindex = cfg->ifindex;

    if(setsockopt(igmp_socket_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(struct ip_mreqn)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    } else {
        printf("Successfully added Membership for IP: %s\n", multicast_ip);
    }
}
```

and start processing packets (not sleeping but in a `busy-loop` like fashion):

```
void read_packets_recvmsg_with_latency(struct config *cfg, struct statistic *st, void *buff, const int igmp_socket_fd) {
    char ctrl[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct timeval))];

    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    msg.msg_control = (char*)ctrl;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(ctrl);
    msg.msg_name = &cfg->ifaddr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(cfg->ifaddr);

    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    iov.iov_base = buff;
    iov.iov_len = BUFFER_SIZE;

    struct timeval time_user, time_kernel;
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg = (struct cmsghdr*)&ctrl;

    const int64_t read_bytes = recvmsg(igmp_socket_fd, &msg, 0);
    if(read_bytes == -1) {
        return;
    }

    gettimeofday(&time_user, NULL);

    if(cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET && cmsg->cmsg_type == SCM_TIMESTAMP) {
        memcpy(&time_kernel, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof(struct timeval));
    }

    if(verify_rtp(cfg, st, read_bytes, buff)) {
        const double timediff = (time_user.tv_sec - time_kernel.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (time_user.tv_usec - time_kernel.tv_usec);
        if(timediff > st->stats.latency_us) {
            st->stats.latency_us = timediff;
        }
    }
}



int main(...) {
    ....
    while(!is_global_exit) {
        read_packets_recvmsg_with_latency(&cfg, &st, buffer, igmp_socket_fd);
    }
}
```

That's pretty much it.

Please not that in the described use case where I start to lose packets I don't use `SHARED UMEM`, it's just a single RX-Queue receiving a multicast-stream. In case I process a smaller multicast-stream of around `150.000 pps` - the AF-XDP solution doesn't lose any packets. But it is also the other way around - for around `520.000 pps` on the same RX-Queue (using `SHARED UMEM`) I get a loss of `12.000 pps`.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Don't know how to help, sorry. But one thing you might want to try at least is to remove those `bpf_trace_printk()` from your BPF program, they're bad for performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything :( What I noticed though: The relative packet lost rate is increasing with time (this means for example it is not steady at e.g. `0.30%`)

Comment: For whatever reason I am able to process `2 x 3Gbit/s`-Streams via Shared Umem on the same RX-Queue (2 Sockets) but I am not able to process `1 x 4.5Gbit/s` stream on 1 Socket. Is there a limitation on the RX-Ring of a socket?

Comment: FYI I also found unexplained packet loss and managed to reproduce it using the XDP tutorial code here where I created an issue [1]. Hopefully they'll comment soon...
[1] https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/issues/116

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I am going crazy because of this issue because I am always thinking it has to be a bug in my program @simonhf